# Returning a struct pointer from class method

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, definition, class-method

EDIT: Changed example code to code from my project that doesn't work.

I'm writing code in C++, learning templates and got stuck with some problem.
There's a class:

```
template<class T, class Cmp>
class AVLtree {
public:
    AVLtree(const Cmp& _cmp) : root(nullptr), cmp(_cmp) {}
    AVLtree(const AVLtree& ref);
    ~AVLtree();

    AVLtree& operator = (const AVLtree& ref);

    void Add(const T& key);
    void TraverseDfs(void (*visit)(const T& key));
private:
    struct Node {
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
        T key;
        int balance;
        unsigned int height;
        unsigned int inheritence;

        Node(const T& _key) : left(nullptr), right(nullptr), key(_key), balance(0), height(1), inheritence(1) {}
    };
    Node* root;
    Cmp cmp;

    void deleteTree(Node* root);
    void traverse(Node* node, void(*visit) (const T& key));
    Node* addNode(Node* node, const T& key);
    Node* removeNode(Node* p, T key);
    int bfactor(Node* node);
    unsigned int height(Node* node);
    void fixheight(Node* node);
    Node* rotateRight(Node* p);
    Node* rotateLeft(Node* q);
    Node* balance(Node* p);
    Node* findmin(Node* p);
    Node* removemin(Node* p);
};
```

I want to define method `addNode(Node* node, const T& key)` out of class and here's what I write:

```
template<class T, class Cmp>
AVLtree<T, Cmp>::Node* AVLtree<T, Cmp>::addNode(Node* node, const T& key) {
    return new Node(key);
    if (!node) {
        return new Node(key);
    }
    if (cmp(key, node->key)) {
        node->left = addNode(node->left, key);
    }
    else {
        node->right = addNode(node->right, key);
    }
}
```

Then I try to run program and get such errors and warnings:

> warning C4346: 'Node': dependent name is not a type

> message : prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type

> error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Node'

> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'

> error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)

It seems that I'm doing something wrong because, if I define method `addNode(Node* node, const T& key)` inside class, it works fine:

```
template<class T, class Cmp>
class AVLtree {
public:
   ...
private:
   ...
   Node* addNode(Node* node, const T& key) {
        return new Node(key);
        if (!node) {
            return new Node(key);
        }
        if (cmp(key, node->key)) {
            node->left = addNode(node->left, key);
        }
        else {
            node->right = addNode(node->right, key);
        }
     }
};
```

Any guesses what might be wrong?

Comment: `prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type`. Did you try this?

Comment: Fix your compilation errors first, you have a missing `;` after struct definition.

Comment: Once you fix the missing semicolon, then the issue [does not occur](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cce92c314db69acd).

Comment: @pptaszni sorry, this's an example of code, fixed it.

Comment: @AcidDica Do not simply type in your code that you claim gives you the compiler errors.  Instead, take the *exact* code, copy it, and paste it into the text window.  Otherwise you lead persons down the wrong path in attempting to solve your problem.

Comment: The first error even have a message that tells you how to solve it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can I ask you to reconsider? It's a MSVC bug IMHO. Gcc does accept OP's code: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bde902200a108c18 (I've got an answer pending)

Comment: @YSC coliru never worked for me so moved to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Mq9s18vod) – there both gcc and clang reject with hint to typename being missing – and to me this appears correct, as preceding return type (other than trailing) is not yet *inside* the function...

Comment: It looks like the `typename` is no longer required in C++20. C++17 [\[temp.res\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#5) makes special cases for just base classes and types elaborated with `class` or `struct` or `union` or `enum`. C++20 [\[temp.res\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#5) has a bunch more, including the return type of a function definition at namespace scope.

Comment: @Aconcagua But add `-std=c++20` to the gcc compiler at godbolt, and the error goes away. (See my previous comment.) Looks like clang might not have this change yet, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answers. Got a solution:

Just added `typename` before method definition outside of class. It looks like this:

```
template<class T, class Cmp>
typename AVLtree<T, Cmp>::Node* AVLtree<T, Cmp>::addNode(Node* node, const T& key) {
   ... 
}
```

It seems that this is some spicialization of Visual Studio because I can see that other compilers work fine with such code without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that I'm doing something wrong

No. This is a famous "bug/feature" from oldish version of Microsoft's compiler.

Inside the body of `C1<T>::Work` definition, the name lookup for `Node` is supposed to find `C1<T>::Node`. See [Name lookup on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) for more information:

> #### Member function definition
>
> For a name used inside a member function body, a default argument of a member function, exception specification of a member function, or a default member initializer, the scopes searched are the same as in class definition, except that the entire scope of the class is considered, not just the part prior to the declaration that uses the name. For nested classes the entire body of the enclosing class is searched.

Your code is accepted by other compilers, e.g. gcc:

```
template<class T>
class C1 {
public:
   void CallWork() { Work(); }
private:
   struct Node {
      T x;
   };
   Node* Work();
};

template<class T>
C1<T>::Node* C1<T>::Work()
{
    return new Node{1};
}
```

[live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bde902200a108c18)

Comment: But that's not yet *inside* the function – else we wouldn't have to specify `C1<T>::` in front of `Node` either...

Comment: That's true. Ill remove this answer as soon as I have a computer available.